# How do the effects of the Charm Person spell apply during combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, combat, charmed

On success, the spell [Charm Person](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/charm-person) has the following effects:

- The target is charmed by the caster: it can't attack or harm the caster
- The target regards the caster as a friendly acquaintance

The save against the spell is made at advantage by creatures who 'you and your allies are fighting'.

How does combat work with the above effects? Will an NPC still attack the allies of the friendly-acquaintance caster?

Comment: Just to be clear, this spell is being cast by PCs against enemy NPCs, is that right?

Comment: @Upper_Case yes